# Windows Exporter IIS site whitelist not working? Is there any way to filter the metrics for iis by providing only list of metrics?

Tags: iis, prometheus

Windows Exporter IIS site whitelist not working?What is the format for IIS Sitewhitelist? Is there any way to filter the specific metrics in config.yml file?

IIS Site whitelist not working when filtering to retrieve only the applications that start with 'Api.+'
Looking for getting metrics only for windows_iis_requests_total,windows_iis_current_application_pool_state in config.yml

Answer (score 0):

#### Site whitelisting

I believe you need to add this block to your `config.yml` (or merge it if `collector:` is already present):

```yaml
collector:
  iis:
    site-whitelist: 'Api.+'
```

#### Filtering metrics

AFAIK, windows exporter still have not realized filtering of metrics on their side.

To store only mentioned metrics, you'll need to configure Prometheus to drop all other metrics from this exporter.

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: go_.+|windows_[^i].+ 
    action: drop
```

More on matter read [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/billing-and-usage/control-prometheus-metrics-usage/usage-reduction/).